# How to swipe to remove an entire table column without using ionic?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, frontend, swipe

I'm looking to have a similar appearance as the ionic list:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogQMQV

I want to have the user be able to swipe to remove a column, just like this list. My issue is that ionic doesn't seem to allow having multiple elements per row (only single).

Does anyone know a way or a framework I can use to achieve this sort of functionality on my front end but with an html table? Or have html structure similar to that of an html table (ie. multiple columns per row).

My code would have this structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Just to add, the class that materialize uses to get this behavior is dismissible. This is exactly the behavior I want, but I want to have multiple items per row.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make it with the ionic list?

Comment: Each row of the list displays multiple properties of an object. Ionic doesn't seem appropriate because I'm limited to a single item per li correct?